# customized icon in osmdroid marker android

Tags: android, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I have several stops in route and I wanna display them with customized icons.
Everything works like a charm when using default osmdroid icons.
But when I change them to image from drawable, markers are displayed above the route (see the image).

```
            Marker marker = new Marker(mapView);
            marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(info.getLat(), info.getLon()));
            marker.setAnchor(ANCHOR_CENTER, ANCHOR_BOTTOM);              
            marker.setTitle(info.getName());
            Drawable d = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.bus, null);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
            Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int) (48.0f * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), (int) (48.0f * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density), true));
            marker.setIcon(dr);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(marker);
            mapView.invalidate();
```

Im using **osmbonuspack:6.6.0** and **osmdroid-android:6.1.0** and **Android 9 (API 28)**. 
I already tried to set  `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` as it said in [OSMDroid - Default marker moving when zooming out on Android API 28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811451/osmdroid-default-marker-moving-when-zooming-out-on-android-api-28#_=) or `setAnchor(ANCHOR_CENTER,ANCHOR_CENTER)` but it wasnt working. 
Is there any other solution?

[image: customized icons]

Answer (score 4):

The issue with this approach seems to be related to custom icon resolution, it parse the real resolution but it downscales the displayed image. As a fix / workaround you can move your custom png marker out of `drawable` folder into `mipmap-xxxhdpi` for example.
And also don't forget to set the anchor, like: `customMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);`

L.E. Do not forget to use a high resolution marker(I have tested with png image)

Answer (score 0):

Setting CENTER, CENTER worked for me.

```
myMark.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER);
```

The default placing (without any setAnchor command) appears to be equivalent to

```
myMark.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
```

presumably because the default (teardrop) marker ponts to the bottom of the drop.

Note that you can also replace the constants with other floats: the documentation says between 0.0 and 1.0 but other (bigger, or negative) values appear to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` attribute on your activity tag who show the osmdroid map.

```
<activity
android:name=".MapActivity"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
```

This is [PokkoDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11096412/pottokdev) solution : [Full answerer link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811451/osmdroid-default-marker-moving-when-zooming-out-on-android-api-28#_=)